# Lazy Loading Component

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

I am looking for a Svelte "Delegating Lazy Loading" component to another "real" component. This component should be transparent to the user who shouldn't know there is this "proxy" :

- lazy-load the delegate (using a callback which dynamically import a js module)
- Supports slots (slots should be forwarded to the delegate when it's ready)
- Supports events (by forwarding subscriptions to the delegate)

I don't think it's possible now because no api is exposed for slots forwarding or events forwarding. Maybe a hack by implementing in js the same internal interface has a svelte component ?

**Edit**

I am looking for this kind of magic method:

I have an Heavy component, which I want to load asynchronously

*Heavy.svelte:*

```html
<div on:click>
  <slot {secret}/>
  <slot name="footer"/>
</div>

<script>
  let secret = 'huhu';
</script>
```

I want to be able to export this component like this :

*module.js*

```js
import { lazy } from './lazy.js'; // magic method

export let Heavy = lazy(async () => (await import('./Heavy.svelte')).default)
```

a consumer can then use Heavy without knowing it has been wrapped in this "high order" lazy component. this consumer doesn't have to handle/knowing anything about the asynchronous behavior of this wrapper :

*Consumer.svelte*

```html
<Heavy on:click={() => console.log("clicked")} let:secret>
  <div>{secret}</div>
  <div slot="footer">Footer</div> 
</Heavy>

<script>
  import { Heavy } from './module.js';
</script>
```

I have a "working" solution, which doesn't support "let", doesn't support named slots, and doesn't support events..

Comment: Could you please clarify exactly which interface and behaviour do you expect? With a usage example, for instance

Comment: @illright I have updated my question with your suggestion. any idea ? :)

Answer (score 2):

The best I can do. bind:* doesn't work, slots and events seem to work.

*Wrapper.svelte*

```html
<svelte:component this={cpn} {...slotsProps} {...$$restProps} bind:this={instance}/>

<script>
    import { get_current_component } from 'svelte/internal';
    
    export let provider;
    
    const slotsProps = {"$$slots":$$props.$$slots, "$$scope":$$props.$$scope};
    const self = get_current_component();
    
    let cpn;
    let instance;
        
    provider().then(result => cpn = result);
    
    $: if (instance) {
        for (let [type, listeners] of Object.entries(self.$$.callbacks)) {
            instance.$on(type, (e) => {
                listeners.forEach(l => l(e));
            });
        }
    }

</script>
```

*lazy.js*

```js
import Wrapper from './Wrapper.svelte';

export function lazy(provider) {
    return function(opts) {
        opts.props = {...opts.props, provider };
        return new Wrapper(opts)
    }
}
```

*module.js (usecase example)*

```js
import { lazy } from './lazy.js';

export let Heavy = lazy(async () => (await import("./Heavy.svelte")).Heavy);
```